# How do I see my native asset in the stellar explorer?

Tags: assets

I have a couple of newbie questions on stellar:

1. I created my own native asset on the Stellar testnet. How do I look for them in a stellar blockchain explorer - the equivalent of etherscan? I tried https://stellarscan.io/ - but it did not find my asset.
2. Do I need to do something special for my asset to show in the explorer? e.g. host a .toml file?

TIA

Comment: I also checked https://testnet.steexp.com/ - still cant see my Asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visit https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/.
2. Type or copy-paste the code (i.e. `USD`) of your newly created asset (case-sensitive) into the search box, press enter.
3. Find your asset in the list if there is more than one search result (look at the issuer account).

Comment: Thanks @Orbit Lens